# Java - How to get data printed from a database by only printing the rows with the same name

Tags: java, mysql, sql, printing

I have this code, and I know how to print one row, but now i want to print more than 1 row, I want to print all the rows which inside of Category have "Other". Please if someone can help, I tryed doing it by myself for last few hours but can not manage to make the code... thank you :)

```
public Object[][] getCatOther() {
    ResultSet rs=null;
    Object[][] catOther=null;
    connectToDatabase();
    String category = "Other";
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM product where category='"+category+"'";

        try
        {     
            rs=st.executeQuery(queryString);
            rs.last();
            int recordCount=rs.getRow();
            rs.beforeFirst();
            catOther=new Object[recordCount][6];
            //System.out.println("test1");
            while(rs.next())
            {
                catOther[0][0]=rs.getInt("productId");
                catOther[0][1]=rs.getString("productName");
                catOther[0][2]=rs.getFloat("cost");
                catOther[0][3]=rs.getString("trademark");
                catOther[0][4]=rs.getString("description");
                catOther[0][5]=rs.getString("category");                 
            }
            for(int i = 0;i<6;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(catOther[0][i]);

            }

            disconnectFromDatabase();
        }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,sqle.getMessage(),
            "SQL Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);    
        } 
        //disconnectFromDatabase();
    return catOther;
}
```

Comment: You're only printing one row because your while loop is storing all records it reads in exactly the same location. A first step towards a solution might be to move your for inside the while loop. But, why are you putting your rows in an array if the only thing you're doing is printing them out? Your code will waste tons of memory if the returned dataset is big.

Comment: I am printing it just for the matter of test, later on I am planning to implement it into a table, but thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are continuously overwriting the same data. You need to keep an index reference while calling rs.next() like this;

```
int index = 0;
 while(rs.next())
            {
                catOther[index][0]=rs.getInt("productId");
                catOther[index][1]=rs.getString("productName");
                catOther[index][2]=rs.getFloat("cost");
                catOther[index][3]=rs.getString("trademark");
                catOther[index][4]=rs.getString("description");
                catOther[index][5]=rs.getString("category");                 
index++;
            }
```

Than it is a matter of looping over your array and printing the values.

Comment: Or move the for loop inside of the while loop

Comment: Thank you, got it now :)